# Java Commandline Mp3 - simple error

Tags: java

I'm working on a commandline mp3 player in java, and I'm trying to implement my own defined class based on IntNode. I keep getting a simple error, however I think I have everything I need.

```
Player.java:125: cannot find symbol

symbol  : constructor Player(java.lang.String,Player)

location: class Player
                head = new Player(user,head);
                       ^ 1 error
```

Here's the relevant code the error points to:

```
int i = scan.nextInt(); // User enters how many songs to put in playlist.

        System.out.println("Enter the songs wanted for your playlist: ");
        System.out.println("Be sure to add '.mp3' to the end! ");
            if (i != 0)
            {
                user = scan.next();
                head = new Player(user,head);
            }
                Player cursor = head;
```

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the constructor for your Player class; can we see the constructor?

Comment: Post the code for your Player class.

Comment: Did you actually import the Player class? That is what the error messages about...

Comment: public int data;

public Player link;

public Player(int initialData, Player initialLink)
 {
  data = initialData;
  link = initialLink;
 }
public void setData(int newData)
 {
  data = newData;
 }
 public void setLink(Player newLink)
 {
  link = newLink;
 }

Comment: I got it. Turns out there were a bunch of points were I needed to change data types. As well as my construtor

Answer (score 0):

```
symbol  : constructor Player(java.lang.String,Player)
```

It means you either didn't create a constructor with those arguments or you have an old copy of Player.class that is being used by the compiler which doesn't have it. The former is more likely.

Comment: Yep, my constructor was made correctly, but I was using it the wrong way. Thanks for your replies.